println function make console result look opposite way
before using println
after using println
I only change a one line of annotation. you can see console result. after using println, In console there is method b and method a , not method a and method b.
i know the println make a new line. but why does the result look opposite way ??
there are 2 classes , and 1 interface. i copied them bellow.

public class UserClass {
    
    @UserAnnot (value="A")
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("methodA() execution");
    }
    
    @UserAnnot (value="B", number=10)
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("methodB() execution");
    }
    
}


userannot class
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserAnnot {
    
    String value();
    int number() default 5;
}


import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class AnnotationEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Method method[] = UserClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        
        for(int i=0; i<method.length; i++) {
            String methodName = method[i].getName();
            UserAnnot annot = method[i].getAnnotation(UserAnnot.class);
            
            System.out.print(methodName + " annotation ");
            System.out.print("value : "+ annot.value() + " ");
            System.out.print("number : "+annot.number()+ " ");
            
            method[i].invoke(new UserClass(), null);
            
            //System.out.println();
        
        } 
    }
}



Please don't post screenshots of code.  Put the actual code into your question.

Please add methodA and methodB, too. I'm assuming they have the println inside, too, and calling println inside the loop just adds a new empty (unnecessary?) line.

Well, getDeclaredMethods() doesn't guarantee any sort of ordering, I think.

@Pateman and println is blocking, so it's flushing any buffers :)


please follow this link: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.; 2) probably not relevant, but we cannot see/know what invoking the methods is really doing


I can kind of reproduce that (missing one line break that is not in posted code) but also by adding different statements instead of using println in the loop - strong indication that getDeclaredMethods() is returning different ordering (as commented by Pateman) - just print method...

and I can even reproduce it without the loop, just printing the result
of getDeclaredMethods() and by adding (or not) some additional statement - documentation of getDeclaredMethods: "The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order."

Sure, the declared methods are  not returned in any specified order.  BUT it would be interesting to know why (in OP's JVM) adding an extra line of code AFTER the call to getDeclaredMethods actually changes the result of getDeclaredMethods.

i copied the all code. please answer me again

@DawoodibnKareem  maybe because adding an extra line of code also changes the .class file and consequently the loading/linking (order) of the classes

actually I could reproduce it even without changing the source at all, just running again (with eclipse)

@user85421 exactly, just running the code more than one time can produce a different order. Known behavior since Java 7 (and as you already said, always permitted by the specification)
